# Custom spinner popup list in android

Tags: android, listview, popup, spinner

Is there a way to replace the standard ListView that pops up when opening a Spinner with a custom one? 
I would like for my Spinner list to be Filterable (and/or even possibly have two tabs with different lists the user could select options from).

Is this achievable or do I have to do my own implementation alltogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is you do not need to do your own implementation. What you need to do is create a class that extends Spinner and override the performClick event and create your own dialog to show instead of the standard one. You will then have to customise the list in the dialog.

In my case I also created my own SpinnerAdapter to implement the Filterable interface and used that adapter with the list.